# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel

Tags: android, gradle, kapt

I'm trying to execute an Android project but I'm getting this error. I'm running on Mac with M1, JDK 11.0.11 and kotlin 1.4.21.

```
> Task :common:kaptGenerateStubsAppDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel
```

Here is the full log https://pastebin.com/kzHuad70

Comment: If you're currently facing this issue, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71486970/5670752) answer.

Answer (score 5):

It was fixed by adding

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=--illegal-access=permit
```

to the `gradle.properties` file, after that I encounter a new error saying

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and 
os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64
```

and it was fixed by adding `kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"` as depency

Comment: I get a '[daemon] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option --illegal-access=permit; support was removed in 17.0'